# Check if cd is bootable

Tags: java

Basicly i  need to check if cd is bootable with java. But somehow i cannot find any example about that. When i put a cd in cd-rom than run the java code, i want to see the cd is bootable or not.

I also read about el-torito cd-rom standart but don't understand much. I also found a sample in code project but it's written in c++. By the way i souldn't use any other implemented library, it should be a pure java.

If you have any source or experience about it and share me i'll appreciate.

Comment: What operating system is the CD supposed to boot in?

Comment: Ubuntu linux. OS is matter?

Comment: Yes, different operating systems have different boot sequences.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The question isn't about boot sequences. The headers follow the same standard for all boot disks. The question is how hardware access must be done. With Linux, using sudo, it actually may not be as difficult since there is plenty of data in `/dev/sr0`.

Comment: @Bora On linux it doesn't work, you should have pure java OS.

Comment: @hexafraction: Here's the boot process for Linux.  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/linux-boot-process/  The only way I know to detect a boot CD is to look for the presence of certain files.  I'm not a Linux expert, so if you know a better way to detect a boot CD, feel free to share.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Detecting the el-torito/redbook bootable header should be enough.

Comment: @hexafraction Have you seen any sample code so far? I need to find a sample code.

Comment: Not yet. Still, I advise you to refer to the el torito specification then try to open and read the file residing at `/dev/sr0`.

Comment: Have you looked at java-avm ? http://java-avm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Boot markers in discs are standard, they do not depend on OS.